# pause and play javascript slider event onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im finishing up coding my website and adding an image slider to the landing page. I am very new to javascript so I copy and pasted an image slider demo and tweaked it a bit for what I needed. I have 4 images that I have fade into the next at an interval. What I want to do now is have it so that when you click any of the images the auto playing slideshow will pause and then you can click to resume. I've been messing with it all day looking through forums and tutorials but I'm so lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

HTML

```
 <ul id="slider">
  <li><img src="images/img1.png"/></li>
  <li><img src="images/img2.png"/></li>
  <li><img src="images/img3.png"/></li>
  <li><img src="images/img4.png"/></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var change_img_time = 5000;
    var transition_speed = 100;
    var simple_slideshow = $("#slider"),
        listItems = simple_slideshow.children('li'),
        listLen = listItems.length,
        i = 0,
        changeList = function () {
            listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(transition_speed, function () {
                i += 1;
                if (i === listLen) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(transition_speed);
            });
        };
    listItems.not(':first').hide();
    setInterval(changeList, change_img_time);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {


    var change_img_time = 5000;
    var transition_speed = 100;

    var simple_slideshow = $("#slider"),
        listItems = simple_slideshow.children('li'),
        listLen = listItems.length,
        i = 0,

        changeList = function () {

            listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(transition_speed, function () {
                i += 1;
                if (i === listLen) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(transition_speed);
            });

        };

    listItems.not(':first').hide();
    var timer = setInterval(changeList, change_img_time);
    listItems.click(function () {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = undefined;
        } else {
            timer = setInterval(changeList, change_img_time);
        }
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pYfsY/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a sample demo for you at the following URL using jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/codebombs/ukNmT/

Please check that and modifications needed as per ur needs.

```
//To store timeout id
var timeoutId;

var slideImage = function( step ) {

    if ( step == undefined ) step = 1;

    //Clear timeout if any
    clearTimeout ( timeoutId );

    //Get current image's index
    var indx = $('.item:visible').index('.item');

    //If step == 0, we don't need to do any fadein our fadeout
    if ( step != 0 ) {
       //Fadeout this item
       $('.item:visible').fadeOut();
    }

    //Increment for next item
    indx = indx + step ;

    //Check bounds for next item
    if ( indx >= $('.item').length ) {
        indx = 0;
    } else if ( indx < 0 ) {
        indx = $('.item').length - 1;
    }

    //If step == 0, we don't need to do any fadein our fadeout
    if ( step != 0 ) {
       //Fadein next item
       $('.item:eq(' + indx + ')').fadeIn();
    }

    //Set Itmeout
    timeoutId = setTimeout ( slideImage, 5000 );
};

//Start sliding
slideImage(0);

//When clicked on prev
$('#prev').click(function() {

    //slideImage with step = -1
    slideImage ( -1 );   
});

//When clicked on next
$('#next').click(function() {

     //slideImage with step = 1
     slideImage ( 1 );
});

//When clicked on Pause
$('#pause').click(function() {

   //Clear timeout
   clearTimeout ( timeoutId );    

    //Hide Pause and show Play
    $(this).hide();
    $('#play').show();
});

//When clicked on Play
$('#play').click(function() {

   //Start slide image
   slideImage(0);

   //Hide Play and show Pause
   $(this).hide();
   $('#pause').show();    
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! Very helpful, I was able to figure it out in a few minutes looking through your jfiddle demo. Thanks again you kept me from pulling my hair out!